# Error 500 con PHP en Iframe

Tags: php, formularios, iframe

Tengo un `iframe` que carga una pagina PHP la cual sirve para introducir notas en una tabla MySQL. Las notas son introducidas a partir de un simple formulario con un `input`. El formulario se envía a la propia pagina cargada en el `iframe`, la cual recibe los datos del `input` y los guarda en la base de datos.

El problema es que el código funciona perfectamente en local, pero al subirlo al servidor, me da el error 500. ¿Alguien sabe a que se debe?

Answer (score 1):

Un error de 500 no es un problema del iframe. Si es del lado del servidor.¿Miraste el archivo .htaccess? Puede ser que bloquee desde ahi.¿El iframe está configurado correctamente? Los iframes es que no son nada diferentes para acceder directamente a la página. Si puede acceder a la página en el sitio en vivo sin el iframe, el iframe está mal configurado.

Comment: Al final después de pasarme horas buscando la forma de que funcionará resultó ser  de la forma mas absurda. El <iframe> a través de un script PHP cargaba un documento PHP con un función para realizar las consultas a la BD mediante un include. El documento se llama consulta-db.php y el include estaba como consulta-DB.php. Pues eso hacia que en local funcionara y en el servidor diera error. Al cambiarlo en el servidor a consulta-db.php todo funciona correctamente.